# Skip duplicates upon AJAX requests

Tags: json, ajax, spring, jsp

I am trying to populate a table in my JSP page with a JSON string. My Ajax script in the JSP page:

```
function getData() {
   $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxtest',
        success: function (data) {
            response = $.parseJSON(data);

            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                $('<tr>').append(
                        $('<td>').text(item.id),
                        $('<td>').text(item.name),
                        $('<td>').text(item.answer),
                        $('<td>').text(item.code),
                        $('<td>').text(item.created),
                        $('<td>').text(item.state)).appendTo('#records_table');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Interval**:

```
var intervalId = 0;
intervalId = setInterval(getData, 3000);
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getAnswers() {

        List<Answer> result1 = answerService.getAnswers();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String result = gson.toJson(result1);


        return result;
    }
```

As you can see I am retrieving a String from the controller, which I use in the JSP page to send a request to. In a foreach I am populating my table, which works. But the thing is, it continues to print out all items upon each request (3 seconds)

Is there a way to prepend it with ajax or check if a row already exists?

**EDIT**:
When spitting out the data with

```
$('#result').html(data);
```

and

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

I get the following

```
[{"id":43,"name":"answer 1","answer":"answer of the question","code":2260,"created":"Jan 23, 2016","state":"LOCKED"},{"id":32,"name":"answer 2","answer":"answer of the question 2","code":7940,"created":"Jan 13, 2016","state":"ACTIVE"}]
```

Comment: Why are you converting your `List<Answer>` to a `String` when Spring can handle this for you behind the scenes? As to your main question: it's hard to answer without knowing what your code *does*, but perhaps you'd need to send the list of all already included answers in the AJAX call and filter them out in the server-side code?

Comment: @kryger I did not know that, let me edit my question with more information

Comment: @kryger when using the code of the edit, which is without a forloop it will only add the new records as per interval, which is exactly what I want, except the fact that I want it in a table. isn't it better to change the list to JSON and then do something with it at client-side?